# XQuery exist method

Tags: sql, sql-server, xquery, xpath-2.0, exist-db

How do I check against multiple values in `XQuery` exist method? I'm running this `XQuery` in a SQL statement

```
Select [column1] [xmlcolumn] from tablet
where [xmlcolumn].exist('/node/subnode/subsubnode[.="value1"]') = 1
```

I want to be able specify multiple values `like [.="value1" OR "value2" OR ...]`.

Any pointers is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use**:

```
exists(/node/subnode/subsubnode[. eq "value1" or . eq "value2"])
```

XPath is case-sensitive, the operator to use is `"or"` -- not `"OR"`.

**If you have many values, it is more practical to use**:

```
exists(/node/subnode/subsubnode
              [. = ("value1","value2","value3","value4","value5")])
```

Comment: How do I do a like operator on a path's value?

Comment: @Sam, You can have in a particular location step: `*`, or `*[starts-with(name(), 'xyz')]` or `*[ends-with(name(),'abc')]` or `*[contains(name(), 'pqr')]` or, most generally, `*[matches(name(), $someRegEx)]`